# Adding a new key value pair to a list of AttributeDicts

Tags: python-3.x, web3py

I'm struggling with indexing and updating in a for loop.

I have the following list of AttributeDicts.

```
[
  {
    "blockHash": {},
    "blockNumber": 14262929,
    "contractAddress": null,
    "cumulativeGasUsed": 17784692,
    "effectiveGasPrice": 42175682624,
    "from": "0x603A9D861D793829F836f6C39c560836A71E7125",
    "gasUsed": 266567,
    "logs": [
      {
        "address": "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
        "blockHash": {},
        "blockNumber": 14262929,
        "data": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a688906bd8b00000",
        "logIndex": 319,
        "removed": false,
        "topics": [
          {},
          {},
          {}
        ],
        "transactionHash": {},
        "transactionIndex": 453
      },
      {
        "address": "0xa3AEe8BcE55BEeA1951EF834b99f3Ac60d1ABeeB",
        "blockHash": {},
        "blockNumber": 14262929,
        "data": "0x",
        "logIndex": 321,
        "removed": false,
        "topics": [
          {},
          {},
          {},
          {}
        ],
        "transactionHash": {},
        "transactionIndex": 453
      }
    ],
    "logsBloom": {},
    "status": 1,
    "to": "0x7f268357A8c2552623316e2562D90e642bB538E5",
    "transactionHash": {},
    "transactionIndex": 453,
    "type": "0x2"
  },
  {
    "blockHash": {},
    "blockNumber": 14262929,
    "contractAddress": null,
    "cumulativeGasUsed": 17784692,
    "effectiveGasPrice": 42175682624,
    "from": "0x603A9D861D793829F836f6C39c560836A71E7125",
    "gasUsed": 266567,
    "logs": [
      {
        "address": "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
        "blockHash": {},
        "blockNumber": 14262929,
        "data": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014d1120d7b160000",
        "logIndex": 320,
        "removed": false,
        "topics": [
          {},
          {},
          {}
        ],
        "transactionHash": {},
        "transactionIndex": 453
      },
      {
        "address": "0xa3AEe8BcE55BEeA1951EF834b99f3Ac60d1ABeeB",
        "blockHash": {},
        "blockNumber": 14262929,
        "data": "0x",
        "logIndex": 321,
        "removed": false,
        "topics": [
          {},
          {},
          {},
          {}
        ],
        "transactionHash": {},
        "transactionIndex": 453
      }
    ],
    "logsBloom": {},
    "status": 1,
    "to": "0x7f268357A8c2552623316e2562D90e642bB538E5",
    "transactionHash": {},
    "transactionIndex": 453,
    "type": "0x2"
  }
]
```

When `data != 0x` in the nested dictionary I'd like to add an additional key:value pair. To look like the following.

```
  {
    "blockHash": {},
    "blockNumber": 14262929,
    "contractAddress": null,
    "cumulativeGasUsed": 17784692,
    "effectiveGasPrice": 42175682624,
    "from": "0x603A9D861D793829F836f6C39c560836A71E7125",
    "gasUsed": 266567,
    "logs": [
      {
        "address": "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
        "blockHash": {},
        "blockNumber": 14262929,
        "data": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014d1120d7b160000",
        "logIndex": 320,
        "removed": false,
        "topics": [
          {},
          {},
          {}
        ],
        "transactionHash": {},
        "transactionIndex": 453,
        "Value": Decimal('1.5')
      },
      {
        "address": "0xa3AEe8BcE55BEeA1951EF834b99f3Ac60d1ABeeB",
        "blockHash": {},
        "blockNumber": 14262929,
        "data": "0x",
        "logIndex": 321,
        "removed": false,
        "topics": [
          {},
          {},
          {},
          {}
        ],
        "transactionHash": {},
        "transactionIndex": 453
      }
    ],
    "logsBloom": {},
    "status": 1,
    "to": "0x7f268357A8c2552623316e2562D90e642bB538E5",
    "transactionHash": {},
    "transactionIndex": 453,
    "type": "0x2"
  }
```

In essence, adding the `Value: Decimal(1.5)` to the end of that first nested dictionary.

How do you replace (or update?) the original dictionary in nodeTxLog with the above dictionary?

My code

```
txDetails = []
for i in txHash:
      nodeTxLog = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(i)
      tx_log = json.dumps(nodeTxLog["logs"], sort_keys=True, indent=2, cls=TxEncoder)
      log_data = json.loads(tx_log)
      for d in log_data:
          if d["data"] != "0x":
              dl = d["data"]
              wei = w3.toInt(hexstr=dl)
              value = w3.fromWei(wei, 'ether')
              #How to replace (or update) the original Tx in nodeTxLog with d?
              d.update({"Value": value})
              #This doesn't work
              log_data.append(d)
              #This appends the original dict to the list, not the dict with updated key:value
              txDetails.append(nodeTxLog)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me where your data comes from, but updating the already pasted data is pretty straightforward.
I'd like call it *nested data structure*, instead of *dictionary* that you named.
Note `null` and `false` should be changed to `None` and `False` to run here. I'm wondering how you got the long data structure, from python `print(some_data)`, or copied directly from some files?

```py
blocks = [
    {
        "blockHash": {},
        "blockNumber": 14262929,
        "contractAddress": None,
        "cumulativeGasUsed": 17784692,
        "effectiveGasPrice": 42175682624,
        "from": "0x603A9D861D793829F836f6C39c560836A71E7125",
        "gasUsed": 266567,
        "logs": [
            {
                "address": "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
                "blockHash": {},
                "blockNumber": 14262929,
                "data": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a688906bd8b00000",
                "logIndex": 319,
                "removed": False,
                "topics": [
                    {},
                    {},
                    {}
                ],
                "transactionHash": {},
                "transactionIndex": 453
            },
            {
                "address": "0xa3AEe8BcE55BEeA1951EF834b99f3Ac60d1ABeeB",
                "blockHash": {},
                "blockNumber": 14262929,
                "data": "0x",
                "logIndex": 321,
                "removed": False,
                "topics": [
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {}
                ],
                "transactionHash": {},
                "transactionIndex": 453
            }
        ],
        "logsBloom": {},
        "status": 1,
        "to": "0x7f268357A8c2552623316e2562D90e642bB538E5",
        "transactionHash": {},
        "transactionIndex": 453,
        "type": "0x2"
    },
    {
        "blockHash": {},
        "blockNumber": 14262929,
        "contractAddress": None,
        "cumulativeGasUsed": 17784692,
        "effectiveGasPrice": 42175682624,
        "from": "0x603A9D861D793829F836f6C39c560836A71E7125",
        "gasUsed": 266567,
        "logs": [
            {
                "address": "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
                "blockHash": {},
                "blockNumber": 14262929,
                "data": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014d1120d7b160000",
                "logIndex": 320,
                "removed": False,
                "topics": [
                    {},
                    {},
                    {}
                ],
                "transactionHash": {},
                "transactionIndex": 453
            },
            {
                "address": "0xa3AEe8BcE55BEeA1951EF834b99f3Ac60d1ABeeB",
                "blockHash": {},
                "blockNumber": 14262929,
                "data": "0x",
                "logIndex": 321,
                "removed": False,
                "topics": [
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {}
                ],
                "transactionHash": {},
                "transactionIndex": 453
            }
        ],
        "logsBloom": {},
        "status": 1,
        "to": "0x7f268357A8c2552623316e2562D90e642bB538E5",
        "transactionHash": {},
        "transactionIndex": 453,
        "type": "0x2"
    }
]
# note null and false should be changed to None and False to run here
for block in blocks:
    for log in block["logs"]:
        if log["data"] != "0x":
            log["Value"] = "value_you_got_some_where"
print(blocks)  # check the output
```

Comment: The original data comes from querying an Ethereum light node by transaction hash. What you see above is the log data associated with this tx. Your code seems to update the `log` but not the `block` in `blocks`. How would you do the latter?

Comment: did you try? why do you think it won't? and, please limit your input to what we can copy paste, if you're goint to validate the code against another data structure in real world, it may not work.

Comment: I did try. When I look at the `block` it still has original data. I will edit the question to be more explicit in my ask. Thanks for the help.

Comment: please copy and paste my updated code directly. and check the output. only validate against the input **that you have pasted here**.